# QMap destructor got CRT detected message

Tags: c++, qt

I'm getting a **CRT Heap corruption detected** message when running the following simple C++ code. The error comes from the `::free` method called by the `QMap` destructor.

```cpp
void foo() {
    QMap<QString, QVariant> map;
    map["Sample1"] = 2;
    map["Sample2"] = 3;
}
```

I am using Qt 5.5.1 (I built Qt with Visual Studio 2013 and configured it to target Windows XP by using the v120_xp toolset).

Environment:

- My build operating system is Windows 8 64 bit.
- I changed the **Platform Tools** property to **Visual Studio 2013 - Windows XP (v120_xp)**.

When I change the code to the following, the error does not occurs:

```cpp
void foo() {
    QMap<QString, int> map; // Change the second type from QVariant to int
    map["Sample1"] = 2;
    map["Sample2"] = 3;
}
```

Stacktrace contains following lines:

```
msvcr120d.dll!_free_dbg_nolock(void * pUserData, int nBlockUse) Line 1376   C++
msvcr120d.dll!_free_dbg(void * pUserData, int nBlockUse) Line 1265  C++
msvcr120d.dll!free(void * pUserData) Line 49    C++
Qt5Cored.dll!qMapDeallocate(QMapNodeBase * node, int alignment) Line 318    C++
Qt5Cored.dll!QMapDataBase::freeTree(QMapNodeBase * root, int alignment) Line 349    C++
Qt5Cored.dll!QMapDataBase::freeTree(QMapNodeBase * root, int alignment) Line 349    C++
Armaghan.exe!QMapData<QString,QVariant>::destroy() Line 225 C++
Armaghan.exe!QMap<QString,QVariant>::~QMap<QString,QVariant>() Line 339 C++
Armaghan.exe!foo() Line 32  C++
Armaghan.exe!main(int argc, char * * argv) Line 37  C++
[External Code]
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I didn't get any error with your code, under Qt 5.6, VS2015. Please minimize your code to just call `foo()` in `main()`, and see if still has problem.

Comment: @MartinZhai That function doesn't throw an error, if I move it to simple Qt project!!
Does it related to compiler specific options!? I am building this project by CMake.

Comment: It can be. You can compare options of your two projects, and see if there is differences.

Comment: Thanks, the error is gone by settign "Struct Member Alignment" to Default.
The value of that property was /Zp1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of **Struct Member Alignment** was set to **/Zp1**, I changed it to **Default**.

For solving the problem, I follow some steps: first I created another project and minimize the source code, the target binary file was executed without any errors. Then I compare the compiler flags of both projects. By comparing the flags, I guessed the cause of problem was **Struct Member Alignment** value.

Answer (score 0):

You have to construct the QVariant object first before assigning it to the map.

```
void foo() {
    QMap<QString, QVariant> map;
    map["Sample1"] = QVariant(2);
    map["Sample2"] = QVariant(3);
}
```

should do the job

Comment: It should work without constructing the `QVariant`s first, because `QMap<QString, QVariant>` returns a lvalue reference to `QVariant` and since `QVariant::operator=` expects a reference to a `QVariant` as its argument, the integer literals are automatically turned into `QVariant`s because the respective `QVariant::QVariant(int)` constructor is not marked with `explicit`.